# How can I tokenize my CSV file in Python?

Tags: python-2.7, tokenize

I open the folder and then I tried to tokenize each word in the CSV file. Is this code correct? I tried to read the file and then tokenize, but I cannot see the result. I am new in programming, can some one help me with it?

```
filename=open("positivecsv.csv","r")
type(raw) #str
tokens = []
for line in filename.readlines():
    tokens+=nltk.word_tokenize(line)

>>> print tokens
```

Comment: Python already has a CSV API, so you don't need to worry about tokenizing a file. See [section 13.1](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) of the Python manual.

Answer (score 1):

Python has a built-in [CVS reader](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.reader) and [writer](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.writer)
, so you need to do it yourself.

Here is an example:

```
import csv

with open('positivecsv.csv', 'r') as csvfile:  # this will close the file automatically.
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        print row
```

Row will be a list which contains all elements of the current line.